# Adding a new property to a Laravel collection

Tags: laravel

I access a couple collections like this,

```
    $articleActions = EloArticleReferenceAction
        ::where('file', '=', $file)
        ->get()
        ->keyBy('type');

    $referencesWithValidDois = EloDoi
        ::where('file', '=', $file)
        ->get();
```

And I want to merge them. I cant use `merge` because some IDs in both objects are similar, and therefore one will overwrite the other. Instead, I am doing this:

```
    $response = collect();

    foreach ($articleActions as $articleAction) {
        $response->push($articleAction);
    }

    foreach ($referencesWithValidDois as $referencesWithValidDoi) {
        $response->doi->push($referencesWithValidDoi);
    }
```

However it break here. And when I do something like this instead:

```
    $response = collect();

    foreach ($articleActions as $articleAction) {
        $response->push($articleAction);
    }

    $response['doi'] = [];

    foreach ($referencesWithValidDois as $referencesWithValidDoi) {
        $response['doi'] = $referencesWithValidDoi;
    }
```

It kinda works, but it sends back an object like this:

[image: img]

In which the `doi` property gets overwritten with the current `$referencesWithValidDoi` in the iteration.

So, currently, it is sent back as:

```
    0: {...},
    1: {...},
    2: {...},
    3: {...},
    doi: {...}
```

But how can I write it, so that it is sent back as:

```
    0: {...},
    1: {...},
    2: {...},
    3: {...},
    doi: {
        0: {...},
        1: {...},
        2: {...},
        ...
    }
```

---

Edit: Doing it like this,

```
    $response = collect();

    foreach ($articleActions as $articleAction) {
        $response->push($articleAction);
    }

    $response['doi'] = [];

    foreach ($referencesWithValidDois as $referencesWithValidDoi) {
        $response['doi'][] = $referencesWithValidDoi;
    }
```

Throws an error:

`Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct approach for this in laravel collection's way is following,

```
$response = $articleCollection->put('doi', $referencesWithValidDois);
```

Comment: but then I can only access this "property" with `$response['doi']` and not with `$response->doi`

Comment: of course, because the $response collection does not have such property, `$response` is a Illuminate\Support\Collection. refer this doc for accessing items in a collection. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-get

Answer (score 0):

You just have a small type, should be

```
$response = collect();

foreach ($articleActions as $articleAction) {
    $response->push($articleAction);
}

$response['doi'] = [];

foreach ($referencesWithValidDois as $referencesWithValidDoi) {
    $response['doi'][] = $referencesWithValidDoi;
}
```

note the addition of [] after response['doi'] in the second foreach.  So effectively you were rewriting $reponse['doi'] each time rather than adding to the array.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've tried that as well, but it threw an error `Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect `. It's a collection, not an array. I've done `->toArray()` after Eloquent call, but it's still not working.

Comment: How about `$response['doi'] = $referencesWithValidDois` since that's basically all the second foreach is doing anyway?

Comment: That's how I was trying it originally in the question, still no dice.

Comment: @Tharaka Dilshan's answer worked.. Im a little upset about not getting this to work, but it's ok, I'll get over it lol

Comment: you were pushing singular $referencesWithValidDoi iteratively in the foreach.  `$response['doi'] = $referencesWithValidDois` (assign the entire array at once) should avoid Indirect modification error in my experience.

Comment: Ok yeah, its because collections expect to have the same or similar data resources.  So you would use the put() option

Comment: But by adding a sub in that way kind of loses the benefit of the collection and is a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!property_exists($collection, "bar")){
    $collection->bar = collect();
}
$collection->bar->push("some data");
$collection->bar->push("some more data");
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.